# What is the data structure best fit for fast lookup and memory efficiency on a collection of Strings?

Tags: string, algorithm, optimization, data-structures, rust

In my program, I have a huge list of strings (non-duplicate), which are crossed against a word. I want to check if the word is valid — its validity is based on its presence in the list. I'm running this check on many different words, so speed is my biggest concern, along with memory efficiency for the storage of the list.

**So my question is, what is the data structure best fit for fast lookup and memory efficiency on a collection of Strings?**

I'm currently using a BTreeSet, since it is ordered and I assume it makes the search faster. Also, since the words can be very similar ("apple" and "app"), I have assumed a tree-based data structure is more memory efficient to store them by a Vec.

Comment: You can use a `trie`:  https://github.com/SvetlinZarev/coding-challenges/blob/main/leetcode/200%20-%20299/212%20-%20Word%20Search%20II.md

Comment: @Tha Shwarma I've written a proper answer :)

Comment: I had great success with `HashMap<SmolStr>` solving a similar problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need an **exact** match, then you should use a `HashSet`. It should be faster and more efficient than the `BTreeSet`.

But if you need more sophisticated search/match capabilities, such as searching by common prefix, both case sensitive & insensitive search, a huge number of words with large common prefix, etc, then the hashmap will not be a good fit.

In that case you can use a [`trie`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) also known as `prefix tree`. It stores the words character by character, thus "compressing" common prefixes, which also provides a significant speedup if you search for **many** words that start with a common prefix.

A very basic implementation is just a wrapper around a hash map:

```rust
struct Node {
    ptr: HashMap<u8, Node>,

    // you can also use a boolean to mark the end of word, but then you would need additional code to rebuild it from the bytes 
    word: Option<String>,
}
```

You add a word to the tree by either recursively adding the next word character to the tree or using a bit more performant iterative approach:

```rust
   pub fn insert(&mut self, word: String) {
        let w = word.as_bytes();

        let mut node = self;
        for ch in w.iter().copied() {
            node = node.ptr.entry(ch).or_default()
        }

        // attach the word
        node.word = Some(word);
    }
```

The basic searching is also very simple:

```rust
    fn find(&self, word: String) -> Option<String> {
        let word = word.as_bytes()
        let mut node = self;

        for ch in word.iter() {
            match node.ptr.get(ch) {
                Some(link) => node = link,
                None => return None,
            }
        }

        node.word.clone()
    }
```

But if you want to take advantage of searching "simultaneously" for any word with a prefix, you should take advantage of the recursive structure like in this [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-search-ii/solutions/1512069/rust-two-approaches-using-a-trie-8ms-2-1mb)

There are also some implementation considerations to be made:

- use a faster hash function, because we are hashing just single bytes, and the default hash function in rust is pretty slow
- you can "soft-remove" nodes from the trie after they have been found in order to speed up subsequent searches.

Comment: Why is a trie better than a hashmap for the problem in the question? A trie (unless you do lots of compaction tricks) will use a lot more memory than a hashmap, and lookups involve visiting multiple nodes which are unlikely to cache well.

Comment: @PaulHankin it dependes, if OP needs exact match capabilities then the hashmap might be indeed a better choice. I kind of focused on the `the words can be very similar ("apple" and "app")` part of his question. Either way I updated my answer.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I don't need a map at all. Just a set or a list

Comment: I think the question is reasonably (not perfectly) clear that they want fast lookup and memory efficient storage for exact matches ("valid words".) A trie _can_ be more memory efficient than a hashmap, but requires a lot of preprocessing and clever tricks to do that, but is never particularly fast. You're right that if you have a prefix and want to find all completions then a trie is useful, but apart from mentioning that the wordlist has some words that share a prefix (which is true for example of English words), I don't see the question asking for that.

Comment: @PaulHankin the point being memory efficiency. If two words share 4/5 of their letters, what's the point of saving them separately?

Comment: Because two words that share 4/5 of the letters require 6 nodes, each of which contain a hashtable and a pointer (in this implementation). That's a large overhead compared to the actual strings themselves. You need a huge amount of node reuse to beat the large node sizes. You can try yourself by creating the nodes for your list and measuring the memory used (and don't forget to include the hash tables too...).